# How to create a dataframe using information in an XML?

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I have an existing dataframe (df1) that looks like this:

```
    txnID   date        repID
1   1001    8/5/2020    203
2   1002    6/28/2020   887
3   1003    6/28/2020   887
4   1004    4/16/2020   887
5   1005    6/14/2020   887
6   1006    5/19/2020   332
7   1019    9/23/2020   100
8   1027    12/4/2020   221
```

I also have an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<salesteam>
  <rep rID="r100">
    <firstName>Helmut</firstName>
    <lastName>Schwab</lastName>
    <territory>EMEA</territory>
  </rep>
  <rep rID="r887">
    <firstName>Walison</firstName>
    <lastName>da Silva</lastName>
    <territory>South America</territory>
  </rep>
  <rep rID="r332">
    <firstName>Lynette</firstName>
    <lastName>McRowe</lastName>
    <territory>East</territory>
  </rep>
  <rep rID="r203">
    <firstName>Aneeta</firstName>
    <lastName>Kappoorthy</lastName>
    <territory>West</territory>
  </rep>
  <rep rID="r221">
    <firstName>Veronika</firstName>
    <lastName>Sixt</lastName>
    <territory>EMEA</territory>
  </rep>
</salesteam>
```

I want to create a new dataframe that assigns the repID to the appropriate lastName according to the xml and creates a new dataframe (df3) including the data from df1.

```
head(df3)
    txnID   date        repID   lastName
1   1001    8/5/2020    203     Kappoorthy
2   1002    6/28/2020   887     da Silva
3   1003    6/28/2020   887     da Silva
4   1004    4/16/2020   887     da Silva
5   1005    6/14/2020   887     da Silva
6   1006    5/19/2020   332     McRowe
7   1019    9/23/2020   100     Schwab
8   1027    12/4/2020   221     Sixt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll first have to wrangle your XML into a dataframe, which you can do with xml2. Then, you can just merge in the info from the XML dataframe into `df1` using `dplyr::left_join()`.

```r
library(xml2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

xml_df <- tibble(
    xml = as_list(read_xml(xml))[[1]],
    repID = as.numeric(gsub(
      "^r", 
      "", 
      sapply(xml, attr, "rID")
    ))
  ) %>%
  unnest_wider(xml, transform = ~ .x[[1]])

df1 %>%
  left_join(xml_df) %>%
  select(!c(firstName, territory))
```

```r
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  txnID date      repID lastName  
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     
1  1001 8/5/2020    203 Kappoorthy
2  1002 6/28/2020   887 da Silva  
3  1003 6/28/2020   887 da Silva  
4  1004 4/16/2020   887 da Silva  
5  1005 6/14/2020   887 da Silva  
6  1006 5/19/2020   332 McRowe    
7  1019 9/23/2020   100 Schwab    
8  1027 12/4/2020   221 Sixt
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error in UseMethod("read_xml") :
no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument')"

Comment: Are you also using the XML package? You should use either XML or xml2, not both. With xml2, start by reading your data in using `read_xml("file.xml")` (if an external file) or `read_xml(xml_dat)` (if a character vector stored in `xml_dat`).